# Using different rim that what I have?

Tags: lug-nut, wheels

I am looking into getting a full sized spare rim/wheel for my 2012 VW Passat SEL. 
Currently it has 215/55R17 tires on it, with alloy rims and 5 lugs on it to secure it. 
The local shops offered me metal rim with unknown brand tire for a set price (both new). But I am looking around on Craigslist for a cheaper option.

I found a Nisan rim with 215/55ZR17 - will it work? (ZR vs 
Will the different rim type will be an issue?

Also, is the lug set orientation is different between those two? How Can I learn more (for the future's sake) how to find the right lug orientation for the wheels?

[image]
[image]

Comment: In your other thread, you stated you have 215/65R17 Hankooks on your Passat ... this makes a huge difference as I spelled out there. Can you please update one or the other with the correct size?

Comment: my bad, it was a typo. My Passat has 215/55R17. not 65R17.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the wheels will not fit. If my research is correct, Nissan's use a 5x114.3 bolt pattern, while the Jetta uses 5x112. Not knowing which vehicle the Nissan rim came off of does not help much.

Two other things you need to consider besides the bolt pattern is the offset of the wheel (how it is oriented in regards to the hub mounting point - inboard or outboard) and the width of the wheel itself. If it comes with the same size tire as what you have on your vehicle, more than likely the width of the rim will be approximately the same, so shouldn't be an issue. The offset is much more important. If it's too far inboard, it will rub on the wheel well while turning (left/right). If it's too far out, it will rub on other parts while the wheel is turning. If it is on the front end, it will mess with your alignment and cause you driving issues (probably not large issues, but it will be funky, all the same). Tire diameter is also important as I've already discussed in your [other thread](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/15602/driving-on-a-tire-with-different-aspect-ratio-number-than-recommended).

Comment: Will you mind sharing how you research for bolt pattern, wheel offset, and wheel's width for each make/model?

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul ... Just do a [search on Google](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=2012+volkswagen+passat+bolt+pattern). You really need the information of the vehicle (year/make/model) to get it right, though.